# Ubuntu 13.10 installer on SSD boots to black screen with blinking underscore

Tags: installation, boot, partitioning, ssd

What I have done:

1. Downloaded `Ubuntu-130.10-desktop-amd64.iso`
2. Partitioned my SSD into a single partition with `Ext4` file system
3. Checked hashes - Hash for the `.iso` is ok
4. Ran following command

   ```
   sudo cat Ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso > /dev/sdX
   ```
5. Tried to boot the SSD - This is when the black screen with blinking underscore comes.
6. Tried different SATA port for the SSD - Same problem.
7. New SSD is `#1` in boot order

I am partitioning and putting the installer in to SSD from another Ubuntu instance on a different hard drive.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

What is the recommended way to put the `.iso` installation to the SSD?

Comment: Startup disk creator doesn't recognize any of my SSD's, no matter what file system I partition them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Startup Disk Creator is a tool for creating an Ubuntu live USB drive. Startup Disk Creator is looking for a USB drive, not an SSD. The correct way to install Ubuntu on an SSD is the same as the correct way to install Ubuntu on any other hard drive. First prepare the installation media from the Ubuntu iso by burning a DVD or making an Ubuntu live USB using a USB flash drive. Then install Ubuntu by booting from the Ubuntu installation media that you have prepared, select your language and click the `Install Ubuntu` button in the **Welcome** screen to start the Ubuntu installer.

**References**
[How to burn a DVD](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)
[How to create a bootable USB stick](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You are correct. Somehow I thought that SSD could be used for the installation iso when booting.